# Sharing images using livekit and nextjs

Tags: next.js, webrtc, livekit

I have a video conference app that have all the basic functionalities. I'm now trying to add a feature where users can upload images and then by clicking one of them it gets shared to all users(kind of screen sharing but instead of your screen you share the image you clicked on). Is it possible to do this using livekit and nextjs? I've tried to change the video track but I was not able to figure it out and the livekit docs are not that good actually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to achieve this would be to use a `HtmlCanvas` to render the picture into.
You could then capture a video stream from that canvas with `canvas.captureStream()`.
The returned `MediaStreamTrack` can be passed into `room.localParticipant.publishTrack(myCanvasCapturedTrack)`.

```
const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
const myFrameRate = 10;
// TODO render the picture into the canvas
const mediaStream = canvas.captureStream(myFrameRate);
const videoTrack = mediaStream.getVideoTracks()[0];
room.localParticipant.publishTrack(videoTrack);
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, I actually ended up opening an issue in the livekit repo and the maintainer answered me with the same answer, here's the link : https://github.com/livekit/livekit/issues/2014 but I faced another problem, it works just fine on firefox and for some reason it doesn't work on Google chrome, and I think it's related with track publishing, so I opened up another issue but I didn't get any response: https://github.com/livekit/livekit/issues/2097 , it will be nice if you can help.

Comment: I edited my answer to include frameRate, which might be the issue here. 
MDN says 
`If not set, a new frame will be captured each time the canvas changes`
and your canvas never changes, so the mediastreamtrack doesn't produce any frames. But frames are necessary for the track to be published.

Comment: I've already specified the frame rate in my code but even when I listen to the event of published tracks  it doesn't recieve any event on Chrome